# I want to increment index number each time the button is clicked to make a slider working

Tags: javascript, html

i want to increment index number of the image to actually get the size of the current image each time i click the button here is the code:

```
var next = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");
var prev = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
var imgContainer = document.querySelector(".imgContainer");
let img = document.querySelectorAll(".imgContainer > img");
```

i want this `var imgIndex = 0;` to increment and store the new value which is incremented.

```
let size = img[imgIndex].clientWidth;
next.addEventListener('click', slideImg);

function slideImg() {
    imgContainer.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size) + "px)";
    imgIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this code. 
You may not used the image index top of your function / global value. That's what it is again starts from zero.

```
function slideImg() {
    var next = document.querySelector("#nextBtn");
    var prev = document.querySelector("#prevBtn");
    next.addEventListener('click', slideImg1);
}
var imgIndex = 0;
function slideImg1() {
    var imgContainer = document.querySelector(".imgContainer");
    let img = document.querySelectorAll(".imgContainer > img");
    let size = img[imgIndex].clientWidth;
    alert(imgIndex);
    img[imgIndex].style.transform = "translateX(" + (-size) + "px)";
    imgIndex++;
}
</script>
```

```
<body onload="slideImg()">
<input type="button" id="nextBtn" value="+" />
<input type="button" id="prevBtn" value="+" />
<div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="file" />
    <img src="file" />
</div>
</body>
```